# how do I properly print a sentence using variables defined in my own class in python

Tags: python, function, class, variables, self

So I created a class in python called Pizza, which takes 4 arguments...I want to be able to insert the arguments and then print it so that it comes out in a clean sentence. For example if I put this into the terminal---

```
from Pizza import Pizza
appetizer = Pizza("Pepperoni", 16, 10.50, 10)
print(appetizer)
```

I would want to get this result---
Your Pepperoni pizza has a diameter of 16 inches, a price
of $10.5, and 10 slices per pie

Unfortunately, with my code I keep getting this when I print out the variable---

```
<Pizza.Pizza object at 0x7f17b762f650>
```

Anyone know why this is happening? My code is below

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, name, diameter, price, slices):
        self.name = name
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.price = price
        self.slices = slices
    def myfunc(self):
        print("Your" +  self.name + "pizza has a diameter of" + self.diameter + "inches, a price of" + self.price + "and" + self.slices + "slices per pie")
```

Comment: Look up the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
from Pizza import Pizza
appetizer = Pizza("Pepperoni", 16, 10.50, 10).myfunc()
#you don't need to print appetizer because myfunc does it already
```

and also, change class Pizza to this

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, name, diameter, price, slices):
        self.name = name
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.price = price
        self.slices = slices
    def myfunc(self):
        print("Your " +  self.name + " pizza has a diameter of " + str(self.diameter) + " inches, a price of " + str(self.price) + " and " + str(self.slices) + " slices per pie")
```

so it doesn't cause a "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" error

Answer (score 1):

Great question! It's possible to make the name of the object be a str function:

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, name, diameter, price, slices):
        self.name = name
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.price = price
        self.slices = slices
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Your {} pizza has a diameter of {} inches, a price of {} and {} slices per pie".format(self.name,self.diameter,self.price,self.slices)


appetizer = Pizza("Pepperoni", 16, 10.50, 10)
print(appetizer)
```

Comment: Note, too, that if you're using Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings: `f"Your {self.name} pizza has a diameter of {self.diameter} inches, a price of {self.price} and {self.slices} slices per pie."` Usually easier to keep track of than `.format()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling Python to print the Pizza object, so it happily complies :). Also in your `myfunc()` method you're adding strings to numbers (this will cause an error).

You should try this instead:

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, name, diameter, price, slices):
        self.name = name
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.price = price
        self.slices = slices
    def myfunc(self):
        print("Your", self.name, "pizza has a diameter of", self.diameter, "inches, a price of", self.price, "and", self.slices, "slices per pie")
```

and

```
from Pizza import Pizza
appetizer = Pizza("Pepperoni", 16, 10.50, 10)
appetizer.myfunc()
```

output:
`Your Pepperoni pizza has a diameter of 16 inches, a price of 10.5 and 10 slices per pie`

Comment: for some reason it is giving me this error...... 
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @samdisorbo Make sure you change myfunc() to what I or other users posted. If you try + between strings and numbers you will get this error. You can use commas between print() arguments, or convert every type in the print statement to a string using str(). or use .format() like another user suggested.

Comment: Ok I'm all set there, but now I am trying to implement new variables like cost per square inch, but when I call them, I get the 'str' is not callable error...self.cost_per_square_inch = float((price/(((diameter/2)**2)*math.pi)))...that is what I used to define the variable and then I called it by doing appetizer.cost_per_square_inch....any chance you can help again?

Comment: Hm, are you calling the variable or calling print(appetizer.cost_per_square_inch)? It doesn't seem like that variable would be a string but I'm not sure if you've converted it.